# Using Bootstrap Nav option I need to exclude the end item from Hover

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio

My menu is created from the Bootstrap Nav menu script. It works fine except I need it to not include the last item which I want to use as a button with a click event. The code below shows how my menu is set out in my index.html file.

```
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
            <div class="logo col-md-1">
                <img src="Images/logo.png" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right menu">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Home<span style="color:#FF6633; padding:5px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" /></a>
                            <ul style="background-color:#383838" class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#" style="color:#D8D8D8">Community</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="color:#D8D8D8">Our Blog</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="color:#D8D8D8">Maps Blog</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="color:#D8D8D8">Eng Blog</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="color:#D8D8D8">Advertisers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="color:#D8D8D8">Publishers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" style="color:#D8D8D8">About Us</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Event<span style="color:#FF6633; padding:5px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" /></a>
                        .
                        .
                        .
                        .
                    </li>
                    <li class="search-bttn">
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
                        <ul style="background-color:#383838" class="searchbox">
                            <li><input type="text" class="searchbox" id="search_text" placeholder="Search" /></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

I have tried several different ways to place a condition in my script file to only use hover for 'li' if it is a dropdown class but nothing works. Below is my Scipt.js file

```
var main = function () {
  $('.menu > li').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find('ul').fadeIn(10);
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find('ul').fadeOut(10);
    }
  );
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

I can't exclude the html from the Nav 'ul' so how can I tell my script what class is in use so I can use a condition to exclude it?

Comment: That worked, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [:not](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) in jQuery:

```
var main = function() {
  $('.menu > li:not(.search-bttn)').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).find('ul').fadeIn(10);
    },
    function() {
      $(this).find('ul').fadeOut(10);
    }
  );
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjKYOL)